# Are non blocking IOs still an issue with server side Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

The [Java NIO Socket Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jniosocket/) supposedly hides the dirty details of non-blocking IO from developers, allowing them to build highly scalable applications, which can handle over 10000 incoming and outgoing sockets using only one thread.

- Are non blocking IOs still a pain with the typical version of Java 2 SE/EE?
- Is this framework still necessary and useful?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Both have their uses, NIO adds more complexity. What do you want to do with a socket server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, NIO creates an abstraction over some of the details, certainly. Non-blocking IO is still a pain to get your head around (at least, I find it is) but at least it's feasible. (Personally I prefer the .NET style of asynchronous IO, but that's a different matter.)

I *usually* use blocking IO: for most tasks, this is all I require and I wouldn't gain significantly by using non-blocking IO. In some cases (such as the one you mentioned) non-blocking IO is really the only way forward if you want to keep your thread down.

I recommend that you learn about it, play with it, and then use judgement to decide when to use it in production code. I wouldn't suggest starting to use it *everywhere*...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NIO is very useful. NIO is also a bit hard to work with. 
Depending on your needs you could consider using frameworks that wrap NIO, like [grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) or [mina](http://mina.apache.org/). Grizzly is the networking part of [glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) appserver from <s>sun</s> Oracle.

Mina is a network application framework from Apache.org.

Personally I prefer grizzly but that's just me.